# Help with FeedMe

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to import data from EE using the FeedMe plugin. I'm using the latest version of Craft and the plugin. I've setup the XML file in EE and exported the data. In FeedMe I match up the fields and start the import. However, no entries end up coming in. The logs show lines like "Pages: Entry skipped: 4795." Which basically is the length of the whole file. I've tried different formatting issues but end up with the same result. I'm guessing the xml file isn't formatted correctly. Any tips on correcting this would be appreciated.

Here's what my template in EE looks like:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pages-export.xml");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>
<xml>
    <blog>
{exp:channel:entries channel='site-content' limit='500' disable="categories|member_data|pagination|comments" status="open"}
        <entry>
            <entry_date>{entry_date format="%F %d %Y"}</entry_date>
            <title>{title}</title>
            <slug>{url_title}</slug>
            <post><![CDATA[{main-content}{content}{/main-content}]]></post>
            <images>
                <![CDATA[{main-content}{photo}{file_name},{/photo}{/main-content}]]>
            </images>
            <video><![CDATA[{video-page}]]></video>
            <relatedContent>{markets}</relatedContent>
        </entry>
{/exp:channel:entries}
 </blog>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to close out the xml tag at the end? I've used FeedMe successfully several times. Here's a sample xml file I use:

```
<xml>
    <blog>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="projects" limit="500"}
            <entry>
                <entry_date>{entry_date format="%F %d %Y"}</entry_date>
                <title>{title}</title>
                <slug>{url_title}</slug>
                <summary><![CDATA[{project-body}]]></summary>
                <post><![CDATA[{project-body-expanded}]]></post>
                <location><![CDATA[{project-location}]]></location>
                <images>
                    <![CDATA[{project-images backspace="1"}{image}{file_name},{/image}{/project-images}]]>
                </images>
                <headline><![CDATA[{headline}]]></headline>
                <quote><![CDATA[{client-quote}]]></quote>
                <category><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name},{/categories}]]></category>
            </entry>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </blog>
</xml>
```

Comment: OK that fixed it! Thank you! I also love that you can import Matrix to Matrix with FeedMe. This is amazing.

Comment: Actually what fixed it was checking the "Check for duplicate" on the Title field. When I tried running it without this it failed.